# How to export .html files in a Maven Enterprise Application (Netbeans 6.9)

Tags: java, html, maven, wicket

I have a Maven Project Built in Netbeans 6.9... I want to export .html files other then .class files alone. I want to simply copy them, but I am not sure how to configure this in Netbeans.

Comment: The html files are javadoc generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the HTML files that live in the same directories as your wicket java source files. The usual way to do this is in the project's pom.xml:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- Copy wicket HTML and other resource files from the java directory -->
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.js</include>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                    <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm, btw just perhaps edit the last line to be </resources>. Either way, thank you so much.